# Xamarin PCL that makes requests to REST service and returns models

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, portable-class-library

So as recommended I'd like to use RestSharp to handle REST web service. I am developing iOS and Android application and I would love to make PCL that makes requests to the service and just returns parsed results (eg. array of User objects).

So how do I get RestSharp in my PCL, tried NuGet, components are not for PCLs and seriously bad would be to just download source files and copy them in the project, I want to keep some dependency management in place.

What is the best practice? Am I looking at this problem at wrong angle?

Answer (score 3):

RestSharp doesn't support PCLs.  I'd suggest checking out [PortableRest](https://github.com/advancedrei/PortableRest), or just using a combination of HttpClient and Json.NET.

Comment: This seems like viable solution/alternative.

Comment: So I have tried PortableRest with this setup: one Android project and one PCL project. I referenced PortableRest with NuGet to PCL project and PCL project to the Android project. But when I try to build it, it says in Android project it cannot find PortableRest, when I try to initilize my Clinet class the is inherited from RestClient in PortableRest. If I reference PortableRest to Anseois project too, it says something about duplicity with TimeZoneInfo class I am using in Client constructor.

Comment: @ZdeněkTopič I'd recommend posting another question about the issues you have with PortableRest.  You could also post about it in the Xamarin cross-platform forums.

Answer (score 1):

I use dependency injection so I can support non-PCL JSON parsers. I also plan to give the native HttpClient wrappers from the component store a try. By using non-PCL code you will gain quite a lot in performance compared to Json.NET etc.

[Link to source code](https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile)

Text library has serializer interfaces, Web has the IRestClient.

[Modern HTTP Client from the component store.](http://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient)

Comment: This sounds reasonable too. To wrap requesting in some Container on each platform and just take care of the result in the PCL.
Can't decide which of the proposed solutions should I use.

Answer (score 1):

Below modifications worked for me and will be glad if it works out to you.
Try using modernhttpclient in your PCL. And inAndroid project ensure you have the below packages.

1. Microsoft.Bcl.Build
2. Microsoft.Bcl
3. Microsoft.Net.Http
4. modernhttpclient

Along with that in application manifest under required permissions give permissions to the below.

1. Access_Network_State
2. Access_wifi_state
3. Internet

Ideally when you try to add Microsoft.Bcl into your Android project targettting monoandroid it will throw out error, so try to add the nuget refrence in the above order.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a really simple REST client to perform Http requests easily. You can check it on my Github [repo](https://github.com/4gus71n/Xamarin.Droid). The API is really simple:

```
await new Request<T>()
.SetHttpMethod(HttpMethod.[Post|Put|Get|Delete].Method) //Obligatory
.SetEndpoint("http://www.yourserver.com/profilepic/") //Obligatory
.SetJsonPayload(someJsonObject) //Optional if you're using Get or Delete, Obligatory if you're using Put or Post
.OnSuccess((serverResponse) => { 
   //Optional action triggered when you have a succesful 200 response from the server
  //serverResponse is of type T
})
.OnNoInternetConnection(() =>
{
    // Optional action triggered when you try to make a request without internet connetion
})
.OnRequestStarted(() =>
{
    // Optional action triggered always as soon as we start making the request i.e. very useful when
    // We want to start an UI related action such as showing a ProgressBar or a Spinner.
})
.OnRequestCompleted(() =>
{
    // Optional action triggered always when a request finishes, no matter if it finished successufully or
    // It failed. It's useful for when you need to finish some UI related action such as hiding a ProgressBar or
    // a Spinner.
})
.OnError((exception) =>
{
    // Optional action triggered always when something went wrong it can be caused by a server-side error, for
    // example a internal server error or for something in the callbacks, for example a NullPointerException.
})
.OnHttpError((httpErrorStatus) =>
{
    // Optional action triggered when something when sending a request, for example, the server returned a internal
    // server error, a bad request error, an unauthorize error, etc. The httpErrorStatus variable is the error code.
})
.OnBadRequest(() =>
{
    // Optional action triggered when the server returned a bad request error.
})
.OnUnauthorize(() =>
{
    // Optional action triggered when the server returned an unauthorize error.
})
.OnInternalServerError(() =>
{
    // Optional action triggered when the server returned an internal server error.
})
//AND THERE'S A LOT MORE OF CALLBACKS THAT YOU CAN HOOK OF, CHECK THE REQUEST CLASS TO MORE INFO.
.Start();
```